# New size of folder larger than the old one - ext4 exFAT

Tags: linux, debian, mount, rsync, hard-disk

I copied an old folder to a new hard drive and after copying it I realized that the occupied file size has grown from 1.9TB to 2.7TB.

Old HDD: WD MyBook ext4 8TB, new HDD: WD MyBook exFAT 4TB

Here are some fdisk outputs:

```
root@node1:/# fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD80EZAZ-11T
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2900CF01-6CDE-4725-886D-F4F57B01E0A3

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 15628052479 15628050432  7.3T Linux filesystem
root@node1:/# fdisk -l /dev/sdf
Disk /dev/sdf: 3.64 TiB, 4000786153472 bytes, 7814035456 sectors
Disk model: My Book 25EE    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 972F419C-FC67-4D33-BCE7-71A28F06D61F

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdf1   2048 7814033407 7814031360  3.6T Microsoft basic data
```

Sectorsize seems to be the same.

The command to sync the folder was `rsync -ah --recursive old new`.

Should I format the new HDD also with ext4 and what causes the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exFAT file system is a simpler, more primitive filesystem than ext4. According to Microsoft's support site (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs-fat-and-exfat-9772e6f1-e31a-00d7-e18f-73169155af95) the default cluster size for a 4 TB disk is 128 kilobytes, which means each file size is rounded up to the nearest multiple of 128 kB. If you have slot of small files, this adds up to a lot of overhead.